# Proper use of optional parameters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, optional-arguments

We are using custom datetime picker which till now had to return both date and time. But now the conditions have changed and sometimes I need to return only date so I decided to add an optional parameter. Now the script is this :

```
var date_format = "dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:ss";

function viewCalendar(parent, destField, dateOnly) {
    if (typeof dateOnly !== "undefined") {
        date_format = "dd/mm/yyyy";
    }
    //more code...
```

But even though it seems to work (I made only few tries) I don't like this very much, but maybe it's because I'm not used to the way of JavaScript. If it wasn't because of some sample code I would do something like :

```
var date_format = "dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:ss";
var dateOnly = true;

function viewCalendar(parent, destField, dateOnly) {
    if (typeof dateOnly != true) {
        date_format = "dd/mm/yyyy";
    }
```

But the few examples I saw about using optinal parameters in JS I haven't seen something like this. What is the proper way to do this kind of thing i JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several choices, you have already discovered [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof). If the data is not going to be *falsy* unless skipped, you can use a [*logical OR* `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_%28.7C.7C%29), the ternary [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) `a?b:c` or an `if` with a [logical NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_%28!%29) to check whether to set it or not.
You also have the choice of comparing against *undefined* or [`void 0`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void), both of which will still work even if the parameter is expected to be *falsy*, with the exception of passing *undefined* itself as the argument.

```
function foo(op0, op1, op2, op3, op4, op5, op6) {
    // if with logical NOT
    if (!op0) op0 = 'default0';
    // logical OR
    op1 || (op1 = 'default1');
    op2 = op2 || 'default2';
    // ternary
    op3 = op3 ? op3 : 'default3';
    // compare, below this line with falsy args too (except explicit `undefined`)
    if (op4 === undefined) op4 = 'default4';
    if (op5 === void 0) op5 = 'default5';
    // compare combined with logical OR
    (op6 !== undefined) || (op6 = 'default6');

    // log parameters to see what we have now
    console.log(op0, op1, op2, op3, op4, op5, op6)
}
foo(); // default0 default1 default2 default3 default4 default5 default6
```

Please note that in older browsers, `undefined` was writeable in the global scope and that in all browsers, if you're not in the global scope, `undefined` can be `var`d or set as a *parameter* and so have a value which is not *undefined*.

If you're not okay with that, choose using the `void` operator over undefined.
If you understand that it can happen and don't have to worry about someone shadowing `undefined`, feel free to use it.
If you ever see someone do it, ask them if they could `var` *Array* for you too, or something similar, so they realise they have been silly.

Comment: I understand, but what I'm doubting most is do I have to define the optional argument with boolean value or just check against undefined. I prefer to define it, but from the answers here it seems that it's nto necessary in any means. Do I get this right?

Comment: _JavaScript_ doesn't enforce that all named parameters must be given passed as arguments, but any named parameter will shadow variables of the same name in parent scopes so if they're not passed, it will be _undefined_ even if they were defined in an ancestor scope.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is inside your second code block, in `viewCalendar`, _dateOnly_ will be _undefined_ if it has not been passed, even though it is `var`d above. It will only be `true` if `true` was passed to the _function_.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, very usefull. Guess I'll stick to `typeof` then.

Comment: @Leron so you're aware, if you use `typeof` like this and then debug your code with _JSLint_, you will get `Unexpected 'typeof'. Use '===' to compare directly with undefined.`

Answer (score 1):

I may go with a ternary operator here

```
date_format = dateOnly ? "dd/mm/yyyy" : date_format ;
```

It will look for truthyness of the `dateOnly`, and either override the format or will retain it

Also

```
if (typeof dateOnly != true) {
    date_format = "dd/mm/yyyy";
}
```

seems wrong, it could be

```
if (dateOnly == true) {
    date_format = "dd/mm/yyyy";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use an anonymous object as a single parameter:

```
function viewCalendar(opts) {
    if (opts.dateOnly) {
       date_format = "dd/mm/yyyy";
    }
}

viewCalendar({parent:foo, destField:bar, dateOnly:true})
```

Especially useful when you have a lot of optional parameters.

Comment: Hmm, haven't seen this before. Thanks for that.

Comment: @Leron: this is pretty common, in fact. Jquery works this way all the time.

Comment: @Leron I like to do this sometimes too, but you need to remember that an _Object_ is passed _ByRef_ (as opposed to the normal _ByVal_ behaviour) so unless you create a new _Object_ each time you invoke, your function may have side effects.

Comment: @PaulS.: in javascript, unlike say Basic, there's no such thing as "byVal" and "byRef".

Comment: @thg435 you can't choose between them in the function definition, true, but when you supply an _Object_, it is a reference, whereas if it is primitive you'll get a copy of it's value that can't effect outside the function. `var i = 0;(function (i) {++i;}(i));i;` will keep `i === 0` but `var o = {i:0};(function (o) {++o.i;}(o));o.i;` will give `o.i === 1`.

Comment: @PaulS.: I see your point, still, everything in javascript is passed by value (or "by sharing" as wikipedia calls it).